socket io - client with app rouer next 14
hi I try to connect to socket-io and I get this error, is there anyway i can fix this error?

uncaughtException: TypeError: isValidUTF8 is not a functionat module.exports.isValidUTF8 (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js:120:53)at Receiver.dataMessage (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:517:43)at Receiver.getData (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:446:17)at Receiver.startLoop (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:148:22)at Receiver.\_write (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:83:10)at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)at \_write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)at Socket.socketOnData (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1272:35)at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)

this the code:
app->page.js
'use client';

import { socket } from '@/app/socket';

import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const Home = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const onNewConnection = async () =>{};
    socket.on('newConnection', onNewConnection);
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onNewTrace = () => {};
    const onExpiredTrace = () => {};
    socket.on('newTrace', onNewTrace);
    socket.on('expiredTrace', onExpiredTrace);

  }, [socket]);

};
export default Home;

app->socket.js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('http://0.0.0.0:8083/');


